# How many string type fields can be written in a compound dataset in HDF5 file?

Tags: c#, dataset, hdf5, hdf

I am using [Hdf5DotnetTools](https://github.com/reyntjesr/Hdf5DotnetTools), a C# wrapper on [HDF.Pinvoke](https://github.com/HDFGroup/HDF.PInvoke) version 1.10. in Windows 10 and HDFViewer version 3.0.

I ran the test cases in Debug mode and found that

1. only one string type field can be written in a compound dataset.
   [inside the HDFviewer 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AThS9.png)
2. if two string type fields are written in the compound dataset, only one letter appears in both the columns. (Notice location column and fourth value of label column)

[image]

But when I read same compound dataset file running the test cases in debug mode, the strings are entirely safe inside the variable.

[image: Debug Mode snapshot in Visual Studio 2015]

How can I see the full string data in the viewer?
How to write any multi-column string in one dataset?